# android navigation drawer not showing title bar in kitkat

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-titlebar

In my application , i created a navigation drawer using Android studio template.
It works perfectly in Android 5.0 above devices but the title bar does not appear in Kitkat devices (only statius bar can be seen) , I was unable to find a solution,

The below is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().show();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        linkNo = intent.getIntExtra(FirstMenuFragment.LINK_NO, 0);
        //Make firstItem active
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(linkNo).setChecked(true);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In KitKat, making the statusbar (semi-)transparent is more complex compared to Lollipop+. So the titlebar is still there, it's just below the status bar ;)

Edit: If you absolutely want to achieve this on KitKat, you could use a SystemBarTintManager  (https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint/blob/master/library/src/com/readystatesoftware/systembartint/SystemBarTintManager.java).

But I don't recommend that, I've done it myself and it's not so easy to get it right.